# Why is Wormtail treated worse than the other death eaters?

Tags: harry-potter

Is he a Death Eater? And why is it he is treated worse than the others even though it was he who did the most when helping the dark lord to return

Comment: Oopsies, this is duplicate.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's a direct duplicate as I'm not overally interested as to why he became a servant as technically all death eaters are servants of Voldemort. I was more interested in why he isn't on an equal level as the others

Comment: Yes, but the linked question addresses why he was a servant to other Death Eaters specifically. It is a duplicate (though I missed it when I was writing my answer).